# High CPU usage on Linux

Tags: linux, cpu, process

I have a process that is called gis taking 100% of the cpu (sub-cpu) on one server and 3 % on another similar server (running as HA-pair)

All other servers have are using 2-3% of cpu as well

Is there a way to track down the source of that high usage or a command that shows what is gis specificly doing and processes calling?

-Tried the vmstat ,top and pgrep -P $pidofgis(no child process found) commands
with no results.
Any ideas?

[image: high cpu usage]

[image: top -c]

Comment: Could you please post the result of `top -c` so that we could get the command/path of this `gis` that is taking up CPU time?

Comment: I have edited my post and added the result required in the bottom

Answer (score 0):

GIS usually refers to a geographic information system of some sort.   Some examples might be geolocating network traffic and overlaying it on a map.   What service/application does this HA pair run?  Anything to do with geolocation or GPS or mapping?

Comment: Hello Richie,

Actually it is not that process, it's a proprietary process for an SBC vendor and it's role is to handle call routing processes.